# Animation loop in android

Tags: android, animation

I made a background to animate from left to right. Everything works fine but when background-image reaches right, the animation starts over again.

How can i make it to run continuously so that it appears it is traveling from left to right always (no breaks)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="15000"
    android:fromXDelta="-95%p"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
```